# Replace function with exact number value

Tags: replace

I have a menu with several diameters: 50mm, 150mm, 200mm ...

I have the following code :

```
{% elseif s_category.title == 'diameters' %}{{ s2_category.title | replace('50 mm', 'thickness 50 mm'| replace('150 mm', 'thickness 150 mm')
```

My problem : for the value "150 mm", the code returns "thickness 1thickness50 mm" because of the rule for "50 mm"

I tried to place the rule 150 before the 50 one but same results.

How can I write the code to make sure that it uses the exact value?

For info, I don't know which language code it is, it is a code from a .rain file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I understand it what happens here is that the first part of the statement picks up the 50mm before the second part gets to understand it means 150mm.

The statement here gets interpreted from left to right, meaning when you put in '150 mm' the first replacement statement it comes across is the 50mm one. Because of this it ignores the 1 and replaces the 50mm like it should. What I think you can do here is swap the `'150 mm', 'thickness 150 mm'` and
`'50 mm', 'thickness 50 mm'` around to fix this.

Hope that makes sense to you, if you don't understand what I mean feel free to ask.

**Edit:**
What I think may solve the issue after taking a look at the documentation for you is the following:

`{% elseif s_category.title == 'diameters' %} {{ s2_category.title | replace({'150 mm': 'thickness 150 mm', '50 mm': 'thickness 150 mm'}) }}`

This however also assumes the 50 mm doesn't get picked up twice. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Hi @Fl0ris,
 
Thanks for your answer. 
Indeed I tried as well
{% elseif s_category.title == 'diameters' %}{{ s2_category.title | replace('150 mm', 'thickness 150 mm'| replace('50 mm', 'thickness 50 mm')
but it does not fix the issue infortunately. I've tried also to replace ' by "

Comment: Does it compile properly in the first place? To me it looks strange how the first replace statement is not closed with a ). Can't say I'm very familiar with whatever language this may be, but usually statements like that should be closed, especially seeing as the second one does seem to close

Comment: Little update on that, the coding language seems to be called 'Twig', this is it's documentation page on the replace statement: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, at least now I know the coding language. I will investigate further on that.